# iOS - Am I making a silly if statement error? I think i'm losing the plot

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard, segue

I'm trying to programatically fire a segue in my code, after checking if a username and password are correct (just the username at the moment due to debugging). The segue fires fine when outside the of statement, and the debug says that the username is 'test', which is what the condition is looking for, however the segue does't fire.

```
- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {


NSString *username = usernameField.text;
NSString *password = passwordField.text;

if(username == @"test")
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:sender];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"NOT PERFORMING SEGUE! USERNAME: %@ -- PASSWORD: %@", username, password);
}


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want `[username isEqualToString:@"test"]`

otherwise you are simply checking the string pointer values.

Answer (score 1):

String comparison is performed by

```
[username isEqualToString@"test"];
```

You just compared the pointer value of the string variable username to the value of the constant pointer to @"test", which of course is never equal.